# self-signed CA for all npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, ca

My internet connection need a self-signed CA to connect to internet.

Which I already install as **Windows Trust CA Root**.

I also installed the cert to npm

```
cafile = "{PATH_TO_CERTS}\\ca.pem"
```

and nodejs env also

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS = "{PATH_TO_CERTS}\\ca.pem"
```

But when I try to pakage my nodejs project into an excutable using `[pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)`

It keep getting the error:

```
> pkg -t node18-win index.js
> pkg@5.8.1
> Fetching base Node.js binaries to PKG_CACHE_PATH
> fetched-v18.5.0-win-x64             \[                    \] 0%\> Not found in remote cache:
> {"tag":"v3.4","name":"node-v18.5.0-win-x64"}
> Building base binary from source:
> built-v18.5.0-win-x64
> Fetching Node.js source archive from nodejs.org...
> Error! AssertionError \[ERR_ASSERTION\]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
> 
>  (0, assert_1.default)(!this.bar)
>
```

Because it's missing the required self-signed CA to connect to the internet and be able to download the missing files.

Does anybody has the same issue ?
Am I missing any config ?
Tks

add extra CA cert to all npm packages

Comment: P/s: All my config above is already working. But the problem still exists.